# How can I get a Low-RAM Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've seen several complaints that Ubuntu uses twice as much RAM in a fresh install compared to Debian.  But it appears that using Ubuntu will make my life much easier due to its more recent versions of many packages.

How can I install Ubuntu and then drastically reduce the amount of RAM it consumes? This is for a server with 256MB and no X.

Comment: Why do you care about complaints from other people? Go ahead and just use it - if it works for you, fine. If it doesn't because you really encounter any memory issues then, ask again; it may be possible that there are daemons that could be disabled, or packages that could be removed. But I don't see a reason to talk about that *before* you've actually encountered a problem.

Comment: There is a Server version of Ubuntu, and doesn't includes GUI. If you will be use a server why not just install the server version of Ubuntu? The only thing that consumes tons of memory that is specific to Ubuntu is Unity and it isn't included in Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is to use a newer version of Debian, point it to `testing` instead of `stable`. Another alternative is to use [LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) which has most of the good things of both worlds. Finally, you could also try Ubuntu server, I would expect that to have a smaller footprint.

In any case, all distros can be installed without X or at least can have their X removed after installation. Not even Ubuntu will *force* you to use a graphical session. The main reason it uses so much RAM is its default desktop environment, Unity. If you don't use X that won't be an issue for you.